# Fatal Error in Latex persist after revoking changes

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I have been writing on this thesis and compiling it quite regularly, it worked until it didnt anymore. The last thing i was trying to change was the link color, but since it gave me a fatal error i revoked the changes. The fatal error persist. So i am not sure what to do.
Can i somehow show the tex log file to someone? It is pretty long, im not sure it would fit here.

Comment: Generally, only the first error in the log is relevant (the remainder are what happens as a result of the first). Without actual error messages, though, it becomes hard to debug your problem, so adding the *first* error and a reasonable amount of the surrounding log here will allow people to help you.

Comment: Try removing the *aux file first. Did that help? Sometimes, a package writes something in the *aux file that is not understood by subsequent changes.